# Trailblazer process return in to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trailblazer

I am trying to get the result of the process method to be part of the `to_json`. I've tried overriding the `to_json` method and introducing a representer. However I can't get access to the return in any of them

```
class TestOperation < Trailblazer::Operation

  def process(params)
    validate(params)
    m = TestModel.new
    m.build_stuff
    m.result
  end
end
```

When I run the following I need to result of the process

```
op = TestOperation.call(params)
puts op.to_json
```

Comment: `puts "op.to_json"` should probably be `puts op.to_json`, unless you want to literally write the string `"op.to_json"` to the console.

Comment: if you create `def to_json(*); debugger; end`, does it step into there?